# Como mudar o valor de um date input com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom

Tenho esse input do tipo date e quero fazer mudanças nele pelo localStorage:

```
<input type="date" id="dateMin"placeholder="Data Inicial">
```

Parte do javascript:

```
document.getElementById("dateMin").value = localStorage.dataMin;
```

O que deveria ser feito era o valor do input ser alterado para essa variável do localStorage, porém, aparece esse erro no console: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at"`

Já conferi a parte do localStorage, e ele não tem nada a ver com o erro.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, primeiro vc deve armazenar o valor no localStorage dessa forma por exemplo:

```
localstorage.setItem('date', '2021-11-11');
```

Após armazenar o valor vc pode pegar ele utilizando o método do localStorage chamado: getItem.

```
const data = localStorage.getItem('keyUsadaParaGuardarOValor');
```

Então seu código ficaria assim:

```
document.getElementById("dateMin").value = localStorage.getItem('date');
```

Você também deve verificar o formato da data que você está tentando passar para o input do tipo date, vc pode consultar por aqui:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_suporte_do_navegador

Normalmente, o formato que vc deve utilizar par setar o valor é: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

- Y = ano
- M = mês
- D - dia

Comment: Eu já havia feito a parte do setitem em outro trecho do código .. e como eu disse, o localstorage não tem nada a ver com o erro, até verifiquei as variáveis no console. Mesmo se eu tirar tudo do local storage e deixar somente um ```document.getElementById("dateMin").value = "2021/12/02" ``` ainda retorna o mesmo erro ```Cannot set property 'value' of null at```

Comment: Hmm entendi, vamos por partes.... o erro diz que o `document.getElementById('dateMin")` não está encontrando nada.

Então faça da seguinte forma, para garantir que aquele input já existe na DOM no momento que você está tentando setar um valor para ele:

`let input = document.getElementById('dateMin')
if(input) { 
input.value = localStorage.getItem('seuDado');
}
`

Comment: Você pode adicionar evento no window para garantir que seu código rode apenas quando o document já estiver carregado dessa forma:

`window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('Seu código');
});`